# How do I get the size of a pygtk window?

Tags: python, gtk, window, pygtk

I'm trying to use gtk.window.get_size(), but it always just returns the default width and height. [The documentation says](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--get-size)

> The get_size() method returns a tuple containing the current width and
>   height of the window. If the window is not on-screen, it returns the
>   size PyGTK will suggest to the window manager for the initial window
>   size. The size obtained by the get_size() method is the last size
>   received in a configure event, that is, PyGTK uses its locally-stored
>   size, rather than querying the X server for the size. As a result, if
>   you call the resize() method then immediately call the get_size()
>   method, the size won't have taken effect yet. After the window manager
>   processes the resize request, PyGTK receives notification that the
>   size has changed via a configure event, and the size of the window
>   gets updated.

I've tried resizing the window manually and waiting a minute or so, but I still get the default width and height.

I'm trying to use this to save the window size on quit so that I can restore it on start. Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the code snipit I have for my main quit.

```
def on_main_window_destroy(self, widget, data=None):
    if self.view.current_view.layout == 'list':
        self.view.current_view.set_column_order()

    width = self.main_window.get_size()[0]
    height = self.main_window.get_size()[1]
    #test statement
    print (width, height)

    self.prefs.set_size_prefs(width, height)
    self.prefs.set_view_prefs(self.view.current_view.media, self.view.current_view.layout)
    gtk.main_quit()
```

I think I understand what's happening now. This is inside the destroy signal, so by the time the code gets called, the window is already gone. Is there a more canonical way of handling window resizing? I was hoping to avoid handling resize events everytime the user resized the window.

Comment: It should work with `gtk.window.get_size()`. Maybe you should post your code snippets for saving and restoring window size. I've implemented this function in my project, maybe you should take a look [to this](http://git.tuxfamily.org/wto/wto.git?p=gitroot/wto/wto.git;a=blob;f=src/webtvorange/wto.py;h=a2b822e46ac4fa1a887ec8309c76b3f6e55f5b91;hb=HEAD#l112)

Comment: @LoïcGRENON I see now that `get_size` is working, just not where I'm calling it. In the code you linked, you use the `quit` function for the destroy signal. When I do that `get_size` never returns the new values. But `get_size` does work if I call it somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to fix your problem:

```
import gtk

def print_size(widget, data=None):
    print window.get_size()

def delete_event(widget, data=None):
    print window.get_size()
    return False

def destroy(widget, data=None):
    gtk.main_quit()

window = gtk.Window()
window.connect('delete_event', delete_event)
window.connect('destroy', destroy)

button = gtk.Button(label='Print size')
button.connect('clicked', print_size)
window.add(button)

window.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

I think the key is calling `get_size` on the `delete_event` signal rather than the `destroy` signal. If you do it on the `destroy` signal, it's like you describe, it just returns the default size.

Comment: Ah okay. I'll try this when I get home. What's the `delete_event` signal? I can't find it in the pygtk docs.

Comment: As I understand it (i.e. there may be a more technically correct definition), `delete_event` is what's called before `destroy`, notably giving you one last opportunity to avert closing the program by returning True and thus blocking `destroy`. I've used this in the past to launch a "Save/Don't save/Cancel" dialog when users have a modified document open when they try to exit a program.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
while gtk.events_pending():
    gtk.main_iteration_do(False)
```

right before calling `window.get_size()`

Comment: This looks like it might work. I'll try it when I get home today.