# What is best signal for writing configuration file in pyGTK?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to save window position and size when user is closing main window of my application, but i cant get correct window position

```
myTopLevelWindow.connect('unrealize', self.__onUnrealize)

def __onUnrealize(self, widget):
    myTopLevelWindow.get_size() #OK
    myTopLevelWindow.get_position()    <-- always (0, 0) :P
```

in what signal handler get_position() will work correctly? I've tried 'destroy' and it's also not good :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried "delete-event"? I just tested it in C and gtk gives me the correct position/size in the handler.

Comment: You are correct, `delete_event` is the right time to do it. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960915/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-pygtk-window/7985435#7985435) to a similar question for a working example illustrating this in PyGTK.