# saving window size & coordinates

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk2

I'm trying to have my gtk2 application save its size and coordinates
for size I'm doing:

```
gint x,y;
gtk_window_get_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(mainwin),&x,&y);
fprintf(config2,"%i",x);
fprintf(config2,"%i",y);
```

all that writes to the file is -1-1 regardless of my file size
what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the `fprintf` calls, so I'd focus on `gtk_window_get_default_size`.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where you call `gtk_window_get_size`. Citing the [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-size):

> If window is not onscreen, it returns the size GTK+ will suggest to
>   the window manager for the initial window size...

So my guess is: your window is not onscreen when you call `gtk_window_get_size`. This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960915/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-pygtk-window) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

the function I was after is gtk_window_get_size
instead of gtk_window_get_default_size

problem is this function prints 82,25 all the time(size at program start)
it does not change the written values when I resize the window